# Using Dynamic Textboxes in C# Program

Tags: c#, textbox

I am trying to make number of TextBoxes according to number in TextBox1 and I want to use each TextBox value in my program. Their name becames txtbx0, txtbx1... but when I want to use in my program, it gives error "The name 'txtbx1' does not exist in the current context". How can I use them in my program?

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        TextBox[] txtbx = new TextBox[y];
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            txtbx[i]= new TextBox();
            txtbx[i].Location = new Point(20, i * 50);
            txtbx[i].Size = new Size(100,50);
            txtbx[i].Name = "txtbx"+i.ToString();
            txtbx[i].Text = txtbx[i].Name;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txtbx[i]);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it right now, the textboxes could be accessed by using your array `txtbx[whateverNumber]`. In order to make them accessible outside of the method you posted, you'll need to make your `txtbx` array a class member instead of a method-scoped variable.

Something like:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    TextBox[] txtbx;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        txtbx = new TextBox[y];  // Now this references the class member
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        ... etc.
    }
}
```

Accessing them individually by name is not really feasible because you'd have to have class member variables for each of them, but you don't know up front how many to make. The array method like you're doing is much better. You can just access them in other methods using `txtbx[0]` through `txtbx[numBoxes - 1]`.